# Google Cloud Platform SQL instance connection to python app

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform

I am deploying a python3.8 app based on [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/) on [Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/).

I managed to create and SQL instance connected to it and also to interact with such instance (allowing my local IP inbound connection to the instance) launching the app from my local machine directly (following [this guide](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/setting-up-google-cloud-sql-with-flask/)) after initializing the DB with:

```
flask db init
flask db migrate
flask db upgrade
```

The configuration string that allows me to connect my local machine to SQL instance is (in `config.py`):

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = f"mysql+mysqldb://root:{PASSWORD}@{PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS}/{DBNAME}?unix_socket=/cloudsql/{PROJECT_ID}:{INSTANCE_NAME}"
```

Now, if I deploy the app with this line in `config.py` and try to interact with the DB from my GCP app page it fails to connect to the DB. It looks like it tries to connect as an external app (as my local machine does) and gets rejected (as I never allowed inbound connection for the app engine instance, cause it has no static IP).

I suppose the SQL instance is somehow already connected to my app and I could access it with some local link, does anybody knows how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. Being App Engine a Serverless platform it won't make much sense to try to whitelist each different IP associated with each individual instance running your code or whitelist all the [IP address ranges](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb#static-ip) corresponding to App Engine services.

The specifics might vary if you use Flexible or Standard. I believe you are using App Engine Standard and using an Unix Socket along with the Cloud SQL's connection name might suffice to accomplish such a connection. Find the relevant code snippet  [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard#python).

The following connection string for SQLALCHEMY should work:

```
mysql+pymysql://<db_user>:<db_pass>@/<db_name>?unix_socket=<socket_path>/<cloud_sql_instance_name>
```

Notice that it uses a different driver as yours and it doesn't include the instance's Public IP Address.

If you're still experiencing the issue please try to add your `requirements.txt` file as well as specifying if you are using App Engine Flex or Standard.

Comment: thanks @daniel, I had it working with: `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = f"mysql+pymysql://root:{PASSWORD}@/{DBNAME}?unix_socket=/cloudsql/{PROJECT_ID}:{INSTANCE_ZONE}:{INSTANCE_NAME}"` where do you find the `socket_path` info?

Comment: The socket path should be /cloudsql/ as you already have guessed.